# Selenium ChromeDriver Not Locating HTML Elements

Tags: python, selenium, ubuntu, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

My python script is running on a Debian Google Cloud Server.  I am trying to scrape news from
Forexfactory.com/news.  I tested my code on my macOS and it worked beautifully.  After uploading onto the server I had to add chrome option arguments to my code to help find the chromedriver in the VM.  It was after debugging this that selenium was unable to find the elements required.

This is the python code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import os

opt = Options()
opt.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
opt.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
opt.add_argument("--headless")

driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=opt, executable_path=r'/home/rehanmahmood38/chromedriver')
URL = 'https://www.forexfactory.com/news'
driver.get(URL)

driver.implicitly_wait(5) # wait for seconds
uiOuter = driver.find_element_by_id('ui-outer')
aHref = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.flexposts__story-title a')
span = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.flexposts__storydisplay-info')
```

This is the error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ffmain.py", line 16, in <module>
    uiOuter = driver.find_element_by_id('ui-outer')
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 360, in find_element_by_id
    return self.find_element(by=By.ID, value=id_)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 978, in find_element
    'value': value})['value']
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"ui-outer"}
  (Session info: headless chrome=83.0.4103.116)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.40.565383 (76257d1ab79276b2d53ee976b2c3e3b9f335cde7),platform=Linux 4.19.0-12-cloud-amd64 x86_64)
```

Any idea why selenium is unable to locate the elements

Answer (score 0):

Instead of implicitly waiting, use selenium's explicit wait.
Seems like the element may have not loaded properly - hence it was not found.
Try using this.

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

uiOuter = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until( EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "ui-outer"))
```

The docs on waits is helpful if you would like to look into it further.

https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Comment: Hey I am returning the Error
NameError: name 'EC' is not defined,  did i miss a definition or an import?

Comment: Hello @RehanMahmood, yes you do need to specifically import it as well. I've edited the answer to include that. It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Use this for your custom window size. Probably it differs on MacOS and VM.

```
driver.manage().window().setSize(new Dimension(1024,768));
```

Comment: Hello, this is returning an invalid syntax error pointed at the 'Dimensions' Keyword. Any ideas?